# How to connect to an Hyper-V VM?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I just treat a Hyper-V VM which has just been created as an ordinary Windows. I enable remote desktop connection as usual. However it fails to connect to the VM from other computers.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyper-V Virtual Network Components

The Hyper-V virtual network is the virtual network interface card or 
vNIC. Typically, most are familiar with the network interface card or 
NIC in the physical world. This is the piece of hardware that allows 
connecting a physical server or workstation to the physical network and 
allowing network communication.

Hyper-V Extensible Switch Types and Use Cases
Hyper-V supports the creation and use of three different Virtual Switch 
types:

External Virtual Switch
Internal Virtual Switch
Private Virtual Switch

Creating A New Hyper-V Virtual Switch

In the Hyper-V Manager, creating a new Hyper-V Virtual Switch is 
accomplished in the Virtual Switch Manager found in the Hyper-V Manager 
utility.

You have the three different Virtual Switch types available – External, 
Internal, and Private.

When you select an External Virtual Switch, you will be asked to 
configure the physical network connect the External Virtual Switch will 
be connected to.

When contrasting the creation of a Private Switch with the External 
Switch, there is no option to select a network adapter to bind to the 
Private Switch.

Thanks,